# cplex for if-else statments

Tags: java, cplex

I am new to cplex. In my ilp I have couple of if-else statement. I want to use cplex for solving my problem using java API. I don't know how to formulate if-else in cplex.
example:

```
if x>0 then a=1
else if x=0 then a=0
```

Comment: It would be great to know how to do this in the python API as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that the Java API supports the if/then/else structure, however it is possible to do if/then

```
IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
IloNumVar x = cplex.numVar(-100, 100);
IloNumVar a = cplex.intVar(0, 1);

cplex.ifThen(cplex.ge(x, 100), cplex.eq(a, 1));
cplex.ifThen(cplex.eq(x, 0), cplex.eq(a, 0));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more thing for "or" statements, I use a large number like "M" and make the statmenet linear. Do you know whether I can use it in cplex?
like if x+y=2 then either c+b<a or a+p<c

Comment: The 2nd argument of ifThen() is a constraint so it should work if that constraint is an or statement.